# Why do i have 32b Ubuntu after installing the 64b version?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

to keep things simple i downloaded the 64b version of Ubuntu to try out on a spare computer but it turns out i have a 32b version? i even made sure to double check with the website and sure enough i downloaded the 64b version: "ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" and i also confirmed that my machine is actually 64b. so does anyone have any ideas as to why i have the wrong version? and is there a way i can get the 64b version without completely starting over?

- "uname -i" displays "i386". and when i go into the system settings and details it says i have "OS Type: 32-bit"

Comment: Can you add detail to your question how you're determining whether your installation is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: What does `cat /proc/version` says?

Comment: @Mitch use `uname -i`. `/proc/version` not guaranteed to tell the arch :)

Comment: `uname -i` or `uname -p` gives the same +1:)

Comment: "uname -i" displays "i386". and when i go into the system settings and details it says i have "OS Type: 32-bit"

Comment: Either you got the wrong version, or you already had the 32bit version installed and didn't install the 64 bit one you downloaded.

Comment: @EliahKagan if that's the case, wouldn't the installation logs be useful here? (I don't remember where are they stored at hand).

Comment: @Tom Do you have the ISO image that you used to make the CD/DVD/USB flash drive with which you installed? Can you [check its MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and tell us what it is? I wonder if perhaps there is a problem on one of the (many) official Ubuntu download mirrors, that resulted in it providing one file when you asked for another. (Depending on the nature of this problem, it's possible for one file to be provided under another file's name.)